# How to start a Nodejs, Express, Jade webapp on local server

Tags: node.js, express

I've been given an advanced project on a MacOSX computer, that uses Node.js, Express and Jade. I'm a little bit familiar with concepts for each, but have absolutely no experience with either one.
I've also found MAMP running on the dev machine where the app is in.
I'm clueless in terms of how to start or run the app.
The files and the database are there, I know how to get MAMP running, but it seems that files are not located or related to MAMP location.

I'm not really that familiar to Terminal either. I would like to know what should I run to get the webapp showing on a web browser (locally for now).

I' ve seen the application running on localhost and a port, but it won't run now.

I guess I haven't started something yet, but I honestly don't know what I'm looking for and how to run it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node.JS applications do not require a webserver, such as Apache.  The applications are often the server themselves.

Typically, you start a Node application like this:

```
node yourApplication.js
```

How to access that application via a browser depends on how that application was written.  There is no real standard, but it's just JavaScript, so you should be able to read through it fairly easily if you are a programmer.

Answer (score 0):

After installing node and express the starting e easy :)

in the chosen folder:

express
npm install
node app.js

And you will be up and running.

Comment: how do you keep it running? It seems to stop the service every once in a while

Comment: It will stop if you have an error, see 'nodemon' it will restart your server each time you make a change to source file ;)

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that *Nodejs*, *Express* and *Jade* are already installed!

To start a local server you need to create **app.js** file in empty folder, for example in **myApp** folder. Copy this code to your **app.js**:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
//Middleware
app.listen(3000)

app.configure(function(){
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
});

app.get('/', function(){
    res.render('index', {option: 'value'});
});
```

From **myApp** folder: `express npm superApp`. You can replace **superApp** to any name you like. Then type `cd superApp && npm install` and you must be relocated to **myApp/superApp** automatically.
Type `npm install` and after this you can run the server by typing `node app.js` (you should be in **myApp/superApp**). The server must be running now, go to http://localhost:3000/ and check.
If you see something like:

*"Express
500 Error: /home/.../myApp/superApp/views/layout.jade:1 > 1| !!! 2| html 3| head 4| title= title `!!!` is deprecated, you must now use `doctype`"*

Just change `!!!` to `doctype` in **layout.jade**.

Finally you should see this message:

"***Express***

*Welcome to Express*"

Now you can run the server just typing `node app.js` from **myApp/superApp**.